# Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex

Tags: perl

I'm working on migrating some legacy code, and Perl is having a fit on the following lines:

```
$message =~ s/_WIP_list{file}_/$WIP_list{$file}/g;
$message =~ s/_STD_list{file}_/$STD_list{$file}/g;
```

How should I be writing them to avoid the deprecation error?

Comment: https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/04/you-must-escape-the-left-brace-in-a-regex/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the left brace with a backslash:

```
$message =~ s/_WIP_list\{file}_/$WIP_list{$file}/g;
$message =~ s/_STD_list\{file}_/$STD_list{$file}/g;
#                      ^
```

To help debug problems like this, you can add the following to get a more detailed explanation of the warning message:

```
use diagnostics;
```